SSR error when call api by axios in angular urlParsingNode.setAttribute is not a function
I'm encountering a TypeError when attempting to make an HTTP request using Axios in my Angular Server-Side Rendering (SSR) application. The error message I'm receiving is:
TypeError: urlParsingNode.setAttribute is not a function
at resolveURL (C:\angular\dist\AngularImplementation\server\main.js:572895:20) 

Context:
I have a function fetchChirpSketchesCount that makes a GraphQL query to an API endpoint using Axios. The code snippet for this function is as follows
import axios from 'axios';

const fetchChirpSketchesCount = async (username: string): Promise<any> => {
  const query = `
    query {
      getChirpSketchesCount(userName: "${username}") {
        userId
        chirpCount
        sketchCount
      }
    }
  `;

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://hostname/fazeal-social/graphql",
      { query: query },
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    );

    console.log('GraphQL Query Response:', response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching chirp sketches count:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export { fetchChirpSketchesCount };


and I tried with another packages like node-fetch the error happening in parsing url also
the error was Url is not a constructor
so i think the error related to ssr because the code working on CSR way
note: the api that we call it is graphql query
